# test discord bot discordjs just on one server

Tags: node.js, testing, discord, discord.js

When you have a **bot** online **on multiple servers** is there anyway to **test a discordbot** while developing new features **in just one server** so it doesn't interfere with the bot in production.

Comment: just change the token.

Comment: Like Worthy Alpaca said, you can create another developer application and then use a separate token with the bot that is just in the one testing server. Then the other bots will not be interfered with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend making another discord bot (in the discord developer panel) and have it join the server that you want to test it out on, that way the other bot will still be online and not touched while you can test new features with the new bot